# The first execution of the toPDF method takes a long time

Tags: docx4j

During the process of converting Word documents to PDF using docx4J, it took a long time to execute the docx4J toPDF method for the first time after the service was started. May I ask why? Please help me. Thank you

Causes of the problem and solutions

Comment: Probably registering fonts present on the system.  Are you using XSL FO?